# Feeding information into list from files

Tags: java

Im trying to feed data into a library simulation project using files.

```
    public void DataRecorder(int modoFile, ArrayList<?> genericList){
        try{
            File file = new File("");
            if(modoFile == 0){
                ArrayList<Person> person = new ArrayList<>();
                person = (ArrayList<Person>) genericList;
                file = new File("PeopleData.txt");              
                if(file.exists()){
                    //System.out.println("Arquivo ja existente");
                }
                else{
                    file.createNewFile();
                }            
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
                for(int i = 0; i<genericList.size(); i++){
                    if(person.get(i) instanceof Grad_student){
                        line = "Grad_student;";
                        Grad_student grad = new Grad_student();
                        grad = (Grad_student) person.get(i);
                        line+=grad.getPersonName()+";"+grad.getEmail()+";"+grad.getPassword()+";"+grad.getRa()+"\n;";
                        for(int j = 0; j<grad.getBookList().size(); j++){
                            line+=grad.getBookList().get(j).getTitle()+";";
                            line+=grad.getBookList().get(j).getPublisher().getPublisherName()+";";
                        }
                        bufferWriter.write(line);
                    }
                    else if(person.get(i) instanceof Postgrad_student){
                        line = "Postgrad_student;";
                        Postgrad_student pgrad = new Postgrad_student();
                        pgrad = (Postgrad_student) person.get(i);
                        line+=pgrad.getPersonName()+";"+pgrad.getEmail()+";"+pgrad.getPassword()+";"+pgrad.getCoo()+"\n;";
                        for(int j = 0; j<pgrad.getBookList().size(); j++){
                            line+=pgrad.getBookList().get(j).getTitle()+";";
                            line+=pgrad.getBookList().get(j).getPublisher().getPublisherName()+";";
                        }
                        bufferWriter.write(line);
                    }
                    else{
                        line = "Employee;";
                        Employee emp = new Employee();
                        emp = (Employee) person.get(i);
                        line+=emp.getPersonName()+";"+emp.getEmail()+";"+emp.getPassword()+"\n;";
                        bufferWriter.write(line);
                    }
                }
                bufferWriter.close();
                writer.close();
            }


        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Erro: "+e.toString());
         }
    }
```

We have employees, grad_students and postgrad_students. Grad students and postgrad students have a book list of their own (the books they got from the library), while employee doesnt (can add and remove books).
Im trying to make a read that gets only their e-mail and password so they can log-in. But how do I ignore the extra information? Also, when they log-in they gain access to different interfaces, for example, when an employee logs in, he has his own interface. Which interface they should have access to is defined using `instanceof` when they log in. How can I attribute their type for the purpose of logging in?

```
        File file = new File("PeopleData.txt");
            try {
                if(file.exists()){
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader("PeopleData.txt");
                    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    while(true){
                        line = bufferReader.readLine();
                         if(line == null){
                             break;
                         }
                    }
                }    
            }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Form_Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Thats what I started building for the reader.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `String[] fields = line.split(";");` to break the line into individual fields.  `fields[0]` will be `"Grad_student"`, `"Postgrad_student"`, or `"Employee"`, `fields[1]` will be the name, `fields[2]` will be the email, `fields[3]` will be the password, `fields[4]` and beyond will be all the other data.  Look at whatever fields interest you, don't look at ones you don't care about.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I understood the idea of using different fields, but how should I do it with the subclasses? Employee and the students are separated subclasses, and I want to be able to tell them appart for the purpose of loggin in

Comment: Won't the contents of `fields[0]` tell you?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I mean, it will store a string "Grad_student" or the others, right? but how do i attribute that string to a subclass? Is there a reverse instanceof or something? Because im using ```person.get(i) instanceof Subclass``` to pick them appart. Am i missing something?

Comment: I think we're talking about two different things here.  I was taking a short-term little-picture view of doing the bare minimum needed to match a user login to a valid email and password. 
But maybe you're already seeing the bigger picture of reading everything [back] into a list of different subclasses of  `Person`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yup! Thats it. And i have to pick them appart because, for example, grad students can take only 5 books, but post grad students can get 10

Comment: OK, then, `fields[0]` will tell you which subclass of `Person` you ultimately need to create, and how to interpret the other `fields` values.  You basically just do the reverse of what you did when writing the `Person` list out to the file.  And roughly the reverse of `p instanceof Employee` (say) would be something like `if (fields[0].equals("Employee")) {p = new Employee(); p.setName(fields[1]); p.setEmail(fields[2]); ...}`.  Make sense?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Ill try doing that! Also,  for ```String[] fields = line.split(";");``` should i do ```field = bufferReader.readLine();``` to make it work? I didnt completely understand where to use that String

Comment: No, the framework you already had in place was perfect, with `line = bufferReader.readLine();`  All the stuff we've been talking about, from splitting the line into fields to deciding what subtype of `Person` to create to actually building up the `Person` from the individual fields, would come next thing after the `readLine`.